# Left joins with native query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nativequery

while executing my query in sql i am able to get the right results, but when trying to execute in native query (spring jpa) i am getting an error. The error is saying: "query is not understood, so query cant be built"

Instead of left join i used a Case statement and got the right results, but the performance is completely slowed down.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CONCAT(sf.frst_nm, ', '), sf.lst_nm) AS sellerFullName,
  ast.acct_stt_ds AS status, 
  act.s_acct_id AS AccountId,  
  act.site_lch_gts AS siteLaunchDate,
  INITCAP(act.acct_cmp_nm) AS accountCompanyName, 
  INITCAP(act.pfrd_acct_nm) AS accountPreferredName
FROM act
  LEFT JOIN slracct
    ON ACCT.sfdc_acct_unq_rec_id = SFDC_SELR_ACCT.sfdc_acct_unq_rec_id
  LEFT JOIN slr
    ON slr.sfdc_usr_rec_id = slracct.usr_rec_id
  JOIN act.s
    ON act.t_stt_cd = ACCT.spark_stt_cd ORDER BY UPPER(act.acct_cmp_nm)
```

Comment: Please post a block of code where you actually executing the query.

Comment: @Mike_Smith Please edit your post when adding requested information because code does not format in comments Also, please actually provide the requested information, which in this case was to see the code that executes the query. We can't help if we don't know what's happening in your code.

Comment: IMHO this query also doesn't run in SQL. There are aliases or table names inconsistencies. like JOIN act.s or what is ACCT shouldn't it be act etc.